# Interpolation on a graph where X is logarithmic (semi-log graph)

Tags: c#, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate on a graph where data is approximated by line segments, of course, since the graph is logarithmic, those are not segments, but pieces of exponentials/logarithms.

So I need to find a function that interpolates a new Y value given the coordinates of a line segment and a X value.

a example graph of the same type:

[image: graph with X axis logarithmic]

This my currently failed attempt:

```
public static float LogLinear(float x0, float x1, float y0, float y1, float x)
{  
     return LinearInterpolation(Math.Log(x0), Math.Log(x1), y0, y1, Math.Log(x));
}

public static float LinearInterpolation(float x0, float x1, float y0, float y1, float x)
{
      float m = (x - x0) / (x1 - x0);
      return y0 * (1 - m) + y1 * (m);
}
```

Given that the lines on the graph are a sufficient enough interpolation, I need to interpolate along this lines (which are not really lines).

My first attemp is based on the idea that Y values are linear, but the X value should be mapped to a different X to get the correct Y, of course it is not working because If I draw a segment between points

```
Point p1 = new Point(0.1, 20);
Point p2 = new Point(10,60);
```

then for X = 1 I would expect to find Y = 40, but it is not the case.

I would also expect that result by inverting the slope with

```
Point p1 = new Point(10, 20);
Point p2 = new Point(0.1,60);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it returned 40 as you expected.   Are you sure you passed the parameters in the right sequence?

```
void Main()
{
    Math.Log(.1f).Dump();
    LogLinear(0.1f,10,20,60,1).Dump();
    LogLinear(10,0.1f,20,60,1).Dump();
}
public static float LogLinear(float x0, float x1, float y0, float y1, float x)
{
    return LinearInterpolation((float) Math.Log(x0), (float) Math.Log(x1), y0, y1, (float) Math.Log(x));
}

public static float LinearInterpolation(float x0, float x1, float y0, float y1, float x)
{
    float m = (x - x0) / (x1 - x0);
    return y0 * (1 - m) + y1 * (m);
}
```

Comment: oh man, you were right, there was some linq sorting left in place by mistake. In the end the problem was not the semilog then! thank you!